# How many points should be used on time series linear regression if the time series has rapid changing trends

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model, univariate

I am studying a time series that has no seasonal patterns and no overall trend. The trend changes rapidly over time and I want to fit a linear regression model to some windows of the series to make short-term predictions. I am aware that for a regression analysis to be meaningful, at least 25-30 points of the past should be used.

My question is whether this rule of thumb would also be applicable to this case in the same way, as the trend could have changed in those 30 time steps and only the last two points would be useful. On the other hand, would it be correct to use only the last two or three points even if the errors obtained in this way imply very good results?

Answer (score 0):

If the trend is changing rapidly over time, there is a good chance that your series is non-stationary. You can check for stationary using tests like DF-GLS or ADF.

If your series is indeed non-stationary, you have to make it stationary before moving on to estimation and predictions. Here, you can have 2 possibilities:

- Difference stationary: taking differences will make the series
  stationary. If the series is Integrated of Order 1 or I(1), the first
  difference will make it statioanry.
- Trend stationary: differencing will not work because of a
  deterministic trend. You can detrend the series or include a trend
  variable in your model.

Since you plan to use past values to predict ahead, I would suggest ARIMA approach for your entire data. It will allow you to use any differencing you need, account for trends, as well as include past behaviour using AR and MA terms. ARIMA models are usually good with predictions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I was asking about regression because my ultimate goal is the comparison of methods, their initial assumptions and results on the same time series. Does the series have to be stationary to be fitted by regression?

Comment: You can still run the regression, but your results may not be reliable if the series is non-stationary. Since you will be comparing it with other methods, you will see that the results won't be as good if series is non-stationary.